# Randomized and deterministic reduction

Tags: np-complete, reductions

Given a problem $X$, to show it is is $\sf NP$-complete, one usually shows a deterministic reduction from an $\sf NP$-complete problem.

If it is hard to show deterministic reduction, then one shows a randomized reduction.

1. What does a deterministic reduction give about the hardness of the problem that a randomized reduction does not give?
2. What is the consequence if there is a randomized reduction from an $\sf NP$-complete to $X$, however one can show there is no deterministic reduction from an $\sf NP$-complete problem to $X$?
3. If we have only randomized reduction, is $X$ still an $\sf NP$-complete problem or could it have faster algorithms?
4. What does it mean for problem $X$ if there is a randomized reduction from $\sf NP$-complete problems? (Does it mean $X$ is still $\sf NP$-complete?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's answer your questions one by one:

1. A deterministic reduction proves NP-hardness. A randomized reduction doesn't. If a problem is NP-hard with respect to randomized reductions, then it could (potentially) be solvable in polynomial time even if P$\neq$NP. The assumption BPP$\neq$NP does rule out polynomial time algorithms for any such problem, however – even randomized ones.
2. The consequence is that P$\neq$BPP, which is conjectured to be false.
3. NP-hardness is defined with respect to deterministic reductions.
4. We say that the problem is "NP-hard with respect to randomized reductions".

Comment: for $2$ you mean a randomized reduction from $NP$ complete to $X$ right?

Comment: Right. That was my interpretation.

Comment: So $4$ is not true NP hardness. The problem could potentially be in $P$ if $P\neq BPP$ holds?

Comment: Right, 4 is a weaker property.

Comment: You can ask the moderators there to migrate the question. But generally speaking, perhaps it would be a good idea to restrain yourself on asking questions, trying to answer them on your own for longer before asking them online.

Comment: This site cannot replace basic education on the topic. A good start would be reading some lecture notes on topics that interest you, though it's better to take formal courses with graded assignments.

Comment: There is no royal road to mastering a subject. The material is sometimes spread across several sources, and it is difficult to reach it without guidance from someone knowledgeable. That's one of the responsibilities of a mentor in a higher education program. You could ask a question here about a literature review, and perhaps someone knowledgeable would share with us the relevant sources.

Comment: Your question is probably too wide. But this discussion is becoming too long, and it's time to stop it.

Comment: On answer to $1$ - I think you mean deterministic reduction from an NP complete problem implies not just NP hardness but also NP completeness.

Comment: Not necessarily: the problem could be harder than NP.

Comment: I see SUBSET-SUM problem could reduce to a problem $\Pi$ whose 'YES' instances may not be easily verifiable. However if $\Pi$ has polynomial time verifiable 'YES' instances, then $\Pi$ is NP-complete.