# Consequence of NP-complete, and DP-complete w.r.t. randomized reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If a problem is NP-complete with respect to randomized (polynomial time) reductions, but not with respect to deterministic reductions, then we have P $\neq$ BPP (See Question 2 [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35822/78055) and [its answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/35829/78055)).

Suppose a decision problem is proved to be NP-complete; and it is also proved to be DP-complete with respect to randomized reductions. **Does this have any real consequence?**

**Context (updated)**
Given a graph $G$, it is DP-complete with respect to randomized reductions to test whether $G$ has exactly one 3-colouring upto swapping of colours  [2]. I thought the same problem is coNP-complete because the "another solution" problem associated with 3-colouring is NP-complete [1]. My reasoning was wrong. Only the associated promise problem (give a promise that the graph has a 3-colouring) is coNP-complete (two different 3-colourings together serve as a no certificate). If that promise is not given, there is no obvious way to give a no certificate in the case when the graph is not 3-colourable.

[1] *Dailey, David P.*, [**Uniqueness of colorability and colorability of planar 4-regular graphs are NP-complete**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(80)90236-8), Discrete Math. 30, 289-293 (1980). [ZBL0448.05030](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0448.05030).

[2] *Barbanchon, Régis*, [On unique graph 3-colorability and parsimonious reductions in the plane](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2004.02.003), Theor. Comput. Sci. 319, No. 1-3, 455-482 (2004). [ZBL1043.05043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1043.05043).

Comment: Since this has been known for 17 years, presumably all consequences would have been worked out by now.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sure, but were there any actual consequences?

Comment: They ought to have been mentioned by Barbanchon in their paper.